Invertible Multi-band STFT (one spectrogram, N different time/frequency resolutions)
I'm working on an ML model that edits audio spectrograms which are then inverted. The problem is too many channels (and so too much compute) are dedicated frequencies that don't really matter much to human hearing. The vast majority of what matters is only in the first ~1/8th of the spectrogram channels. I'd like to rescale it more similarly to the human hearing scale (like a mel spectrogram), but it needs to remain invertible/redundant.
I tried a CQT but the result was super periodic which my model hates:

I also tried making my own multiresolution STFT by splicing together different n_fft sizes, but (very loud) artifacts appear along the borders between bands when this transform is repeatedly applied and inverted (inversion is just separating the pieces, padding with zeros, running one istft for each band, then summing the waves):

How do I construct a

Perfectly or near perfectly invertible complex spectrogram-like transform
Such that it is made up of N time/frequency resolution bands
Where each band is the same shape (number of channels, length)
But have different n_fft such that the time/freq resolution scales similarly to a mel spectrogram?

The hard part is avoiding overlap and/or lost information at the boundaries between bands. Alternatively, a way to transform the CQT to a reversible representation where both tensors are smooth like an normal spectrogram's .real and .imag would also work.

A fairly common way of creating a "human friendly" audio spectrogram is a logarithmic soothing, specifically "Nth" octave smoothing. (1/3 octave, 1/10 octave, etc). What exactly do you mean by "invertible" or "redundant". Can you give mathematically definitions for you requirements? The words leave a lot room for interpretation.

@Hilmar thanks for responding! Invertible in my case means the transform can be reversed to get the wave back with a very small reconstruction error (STFT is ~1e-15 MSE which can prob be attributed to floating point error). With normal spectrograms this can be accomplished when constant overlap add (COLA) is satisfied. I'd like the lowest bands of my spectrogram-like-transform to have high frequency resolution but low time resolution so as to be more forgiving of my model's error which is more in the time domain. Octave smoothing seems to keep the same time resolution throughout?

Thanks. If you want to be able to get back into the time domain, octave smoothing won't work. If you are planning to do any processing in the transform domain before reconstruction? That gets mathematically very complicated because of potential time domain aliasing. The best choice here depends a lot on how "aggressive" your processing is and how quickly it changes with time.

The processing is all done by an ML model with a reconstruction loss that should force the model to account for aliasing issues. If I could figure out how to get something scaled like a CQT but with the smoothness of an STFT, or if I could figure out how to remove the border artifacts from my MRSTFT, I think I'd be golden.

But you want that "processing ... done by an ML model" to be done in the log-frequency domain, correct?  (Or MEL-spacing, I don't care.)  What if the processing for a single frame or a few adjacent frames was the null process?  That is, for whatever reason your ML model decides that no change to the log-frequency data is best.  Then do you want this to be invertible and that you get, in the time domain, coming out is exactly what you put in (for the adjacent frames in question)?

And, BTW, someone else recently asked a question about STFT.  I might suggest that you familiarize yourself with the STFT as it is defined and get really formal with the math.  This is to cover your butt when recombining output frames so that you don't get the discontinuities that you're wanting to avoid.  Are you doing any time-scaling with this? (That is lengthening or shortening the sound duration without changing the pitch or frequencies of the various frequency components.) If you're time-scaling, you need to adjust the phases of various components when you recombine, avoiding glitches.

I believe this answer is the most concise description of what the STFT is doing that is mathematically formal and accurate.

I am doing something related for audio to midi conversion. The reconstructed audio is for  debug use only, and has some minor artefacts. Reconstructed voice and music are quite clear, but not identical to the input. It's for testing noise removal. On a desktop PC, it runs much faster than real time. A bank of 200-4000 single stage biquad bandpass filters are spread over the audio range and sampled 10-500 times per second. Only the largest 16-64 LPF power/frequency readings are kept. Phase is ignored. Reconstruction maintains output continuity. Frequency layout is log and Q is similar to human.

@robertbristow-johnson Yes, it should give me exactly the same thing out as goes in (including phase) as it is an iterative model that runs the transform and inverse ~50 times before getting the final result. Process is Audio -> STFT -> Model -> STFT(ISTFT) -> Model X 50 -> ISTFT -> Output Audio

Well, I dunno how lossy going from STFT to the model is.  If there is no information lost going from linear-frequency DFT data to a description in log-frequency or MEL scale, then you can get perfect reconstruction. But there might be some loss of information in the top few octaves and perfect reconstruction might not be possible.

But I refined the other answer a little bit.  I have described the essential math needed to go into the STFT (one big single band from DC to Nyquist) and going back and reconstructing.

Based on your requirements, the continuous wavelet transform (CWT) seems much more appropriate to your use case. Choose an analytic wavelet (Cauchy, Morse, or log-normal) and tune its quality factor (number of oscillations) according to your needs.
